# how to reverse fetch data in django models

Tags: django, django-models

I am stuck on how to fetch the data child model which has a foreignkey of parent model.

this is how my model looks like

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)

class ProjectTask(models.Model):
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Projects,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=False)

class TaskBlockers(models.Model):
    task_id = models.ForeignKey(ProjectTask,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=False,related_name='task_id_related')
    blocker = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
```

now what I want is to get all the blockers under a projectTask which has a projectid = something.

`ProjectTask.objects.filter(project_id=1)` this will give a queryset right? and for each element in a queryset i want the blocker from TaskBlockers table.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
data = TaskBlockers.objects.filter(task_id__project_id_id=1).values("blocker")
```

Comment: I am actually looking for a method which can access blocker of TaskBlocker model from ProjectTask model.

Comment: then you have to fetch data from `ProjectTask` First and then use it in `TaskBlocker`.